# Устройство видео потока. ffmpeg

Tags: c#, видео, ffmpeg

Я формирую видео поток с помощью ffmpeg и отправляю по сети. Принимаю и воспроизвожу видео на другой стороне с помощью ffplay.
Ffplay меня не устраивает. Я хочу принимать данные вручную (своим приложением) и отображать удобными мне способами.
Принимать то я принимаю, но понятия не имею как обработать эти данные.
Те библиотеки для работы с видео, что я сумел найти, все работают с видеофайлами и отказываются проигрывать поток из сети.
Нашол aforge, он умеет проигрывать по кадрово.
Как распарсить мой поток на отдельные кадры?
Нужно понять как он устроен.

Или посоветуйте вариант по лучше.

Comment: Ну вот OpenCV, например, принимает поток из сети (и любой MRL, который сможет обработать). При наличии ffmpeg библиотек "под капотом" будут  использоваться они.

Comment: Ну... DirectX умеет видео-потоки (и аудио) воспроизводить через DirectPlay/DirectShow, он достаточно универсален, трудность - нужно "принимающий" фильтр правильно написать. Ещё минус - решение только для винды. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144609/displaying-a-video-in-directx Ещё... как вариант, хорошо бы указать какой(ие) видеокодек вас конкретно интерисует. Возможно есть реализация этого кодека в других библиотеках, как более узкое решение.

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать ту же библиотеку ffmpeg. А начать с вызова функции `avformat_open_input`, которая первым аргументом принимает любой (валидный) адрес источника данных, в том числе и url.

[Пример чтения потока](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11054652/4711135)